# getting errors while installing mariadb

Tags: ubuntu, mariadb

So i am downloading mariadb from `$ curl -sS https://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb_repo_setup | sudo bash` but i get this error

```
E: The repository 'http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/10.0/ubuntu raring Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/10.0/ubuntu precise Release' does not have a Release file.
# [error] Failed to add trusted package signing keys
```

does anyone have the same problem or know how to fix this?

i tried to install maria db like above but i always get errors. i am following a tutorial for how to make a website on a old device. i put ubuntu server on my laptop and the installation is done.
this is the tutorial i was following: (https://www.makeuseof.com/host-website-using-pc-or-laptop/)

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you attempting to install onto? Do you care what MariaDB version to use?

Comment: you appear to be using ubuntu 12.04, which reached end of life 6 years ago.  you are not going to find any repositories still supporting it.  if you really want to use your old, insecure ubuntu version, you are going to need to build mariadb from source.

Comment: Unless you chose an EOL MariaDB from about the same time as your distro version, I have doubts it will even compile. Start with a modern OS, and the MariaDB version will be there.